# How to extract elements from Pandas Series Rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, series

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

I am trying to loop through and extract the last two elements (letters e.g. QC or ON) from each row on the series/column.
I would have thought the contents of each row is a string and not floats. Either way what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pleas do not post links to images of text/code. Instead, edit your question it include the info as plaintext, usually formatted as code.

Comment: look at: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html

Comment: Your first value is `NaN`(type float) which you can't index i.e. use `[]`. You can completely avoid writing a loop here. Try `data2.str[-2:]`

Comment: Thank you ALL  ...your suggestions worked out. 
@Bohemian Thank you for the kind correction

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is the NaN values in the column, this code should work for you:

```
city = data2.fillna('').str.slice(-2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Series.iteritems](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html)

```py
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C'])

for index, value in s.items():

    print(f"Index : {index}, Value : {value}")
Index : 0, Value : A
Index : 1, Value : B
Index : 2, Value : C
```